# What is the difference between a cbp file and a cpp file?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

In code blocks their default file is main.cbp so I usually change it to main.cpp. But there doesn't seem to be a difference between their performances. But then again I just began coding in C++ so I'd like to know if there are any differences before I get too deep.

Comment: I've never used code blocks, but I would guess that 'cbp' stands for code blocks project. And according to this page: http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/File_formats_description -- my guess was correct. It's an xml file used to tell code blocks how to build your project, whereas cpp is a common extension for a file containing C++ code.

Comment: Thanks so much. That makes a lot of sense. So then I guess there's not much difference after all

Comment: I'm not sure by what standard you are measuring, but it seems to me that there is quite a large difference.

Comment: Okay, so please explain

Comment: One is C++ code that determines how your program behaves, the other is an xml file that determines how your program is built. You don't think that's a large difference?

Comment: "I usually have to" Why do you think so?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I wasn't sure because they both build the same in code blocks. That's where my confusion was coming from

Comment: @n.m. Sorry, I didn't mean that I had to change it, I just change it for my own sanity. I guess the wording was poor on my part

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that the two files are interchangeable. They are not. They serve completely different purposes. I'm not sure exactly what you are doing, but if you changing the extension of the file to 'cpp' and placing C++ code in there, you are essentially erasing your project file. Since I don't use Code Blocks, I don't know what it does in that situation. But if your program is still building, then I would guess that it is simply building the project with default settings (since it doesn't have a project file to get settings from, since you erased it).

Comment: What you should probably be doing is keeping the cbp file as it is, and adding your cpp files in addition to it, not in place of it.

Comment: Benjamins guesses on what you do seem quite plausible. Would you like to actually specify what you are doing? I.e. please confirm the guesses or explain what is different.

Answer (score 2):

.cbp is the extension for a codeblocks solution file. Usually the project file will contain the .cpp file. chp files dont contain the actual source code but the procedure for codeblocks to associate files.

In a nutshell, .cpp contains the source code while cbp files dont.

**Why do you have to know about that?**

Answer: when passing source code, cpp file is the only format that can be opened for IDE other than codeblocks eg. Dev C++